# How do I add a calculated column in sql workbench / j

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, calculated-columns

How do I add a calculated column in SQL workbench/j (as client for amazon redshift)

```
ALTER TABLE table_one
ADD COLUMN test_column
AS (
SELECT
(CASE WHEN LEFT(name,3) = "Ads" THEN "ok" ELSE "no" END) 
FROM table_one
)
VARCHAR(100) NULL;
```

I've also tried substituting the `SELECT` statement with a constant string value and it did not work.

Comment: I think the better way is to `ALTER TABLE` and then do `UPDATE` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by :

```
    ALTER TABLE table_one
    ADD COLUMN test_column VARCHAR(100) NULL;

    GO;
```

then update all rows by :

```
UPDATE table_one
SET test_column = (CASE WHEN LEFT(name,3) = "Ads" THEN "ok" ELSE "no" END)
```

Comment: This is not the same as a computed column, because it won't populate test_column for newly inserted rows. You'll have to run the UPDATE statement periodically (or add it as a table trigger, which is not supported in Redshift).

Answer (score 2):

Adding for future seekers: MySQL 5.7 supports computed columns, which it refers to as "generated" columns. In MySQL Workbench you can add a formula by selecting the row in the Columns tab, clicking the 'Generated' button, and adding the formula (without an equals symbol at the start) in the Default/Expression field.

Comment: The question is about Amazon Redshift, not about MySQL. And it's about SQL Workbench/J not about MySQL Workbench

Comment: Also, the SQL standard specifies `<data type> GENERATED [ALWAYS] AS (function)' [STORED | VIRTUAL]` -  Firebird uses the `COMPUTED BY` syntax (it's had them a long time). The word `VIRTUAL` is also used for this which is unfortunate, as it is also one of the standard's storage class specifiers (i.e. [STORED | VIRTUAL] - the former is on disk, the latter is calculated on the fly).